# Проброс значения url в контейнер (react)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Всем привет. Подскажите, как решить такую задачку:
есть контейнер, к которому можно обратиться двумя путями: либо перейти по урлу http://qwe.rty/test или http://qwe.rty/test/123/321. В зависимости от того, по какому урлу обратились, контейнер отправляет тот или иной запрос. Динамический роутинг настроен, вопрос заключается в следующем: как пробрасывать значение урла непосредственно в контейнер?

Comment: а ты используешь BrowserRouter?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте параметры для описания пути:

```
<Route path={'/test(/:param1/:param2)'} component={YourComponent} />
```

Далее подключаете react-router к вашему контейнеру:

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router'

class YourContainer extends ... {
    ...
}

export default withRouter(YourContainer)
```

Тогда в вашем контейнере они будут доступны:

`this.props.params.param1` и `this.props.params.param2`

Answer (score 0):

Роутер создает контекст, который пробрасывается в твой компонент. Чтобы получить к нему доступ, в контейнере нужно определить

```
static contextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.object,
}
```

Далее можно получить значение текущего местоположения из

```
this.context.router.route.location.pathname
```